# overflow: hidden cosumes extra space in IE8?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

i have below html code

```
<div id="tabsDiv" >
    <ul id="myTabs" class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
            <a href="#ui-tabs-2">Testing it for creation  Testing it for creation subject Testing it for creation subject 
            Testing it for creation  Testing it for creation  Testing it for creation subject Testing it 
            for creation  Ends here</a>
            <a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the css code

```
#myTabs li a {
  font-size: 9pt;
  max-width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

}
```

I am facing issue when i have large hyperlink in this case Testing it.....Ends Here. What happens is css only shows the characters that
fits inside 200px plus 3 dots but it unnecessarily consumes the space for complete text.So if i add another li tag it will start after large space.  It works fine in IE9,FF,chrome but not in IE8?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display:block` or `inline-block` [Check it out on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PgaYx/)

Comment: it did not work. Still it consumes the space for complete text though displays only the text that fits inside 200px

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is another block-level element that maybe reserving space or causing a line break? Just verified the above solution on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PgaYx/2/) Can you post more of your markup or styling, or insert it into the fiddle for review?